# Splitting a double into multiple parts

Tags: c++, split, double

As the title stated, I want to split a multi-digit double into multiple parts each containing 4 digits.

I've already round the double to the closet integers, so there are no fraction parts, what left is a really really long double, that far exceeds the largest long long integer.

I need to split the integers parts into several 4 digit parts, which with integers is quite simple, a while statement like this would do:

```
unsigned long long int IntegerWithSeveralParts;
unsigned short int i = 0;
unsigned int Parts[10];
while ( IntegerWithSeveralParts )
{
    Parts[i] = IntegerWithSeveralParts % 10000;
    IntegerWithSeveralParts /= 10000;
    ++ i;
}
```

Yes, I know the parts are in reverse order, but a vector could fix that. The problem is, I can't perform modular on floats and doubles, which is quite a big deal to me. I can convert those into strings, and do the splitting from that, but that is quite time-consuming as that will include the use of streams.

Is there anyway else to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fmod()` family of functions from `<cmath>` provides the floating point remainder of `x / y` where `x` and `y` are the two arguments to the function.

Answer (score 3):

You could always "promote" the fractional part to an integer by multiplying by 10000 then modulating by 10000. This will take the first four decimal places and make an int out of them. Do this repeatedly to get more 4-digit chunks.

Comment: I do know that, but I am wondering how I can mod a floating-point value. But as @JonathanLeffler stated that the function I need is in cmath.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [fmod](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/fmod/) for floating point modular arithmatic. But a easier solution is to use stringstream to convert the float into string and just split up the string into piece with up to 4 length.

Comment: Why? I think stream operations are pretty costly, and then there's `stringstream` to `string`, and `string` to `int`. Which just seem to be really really costly.

Comment: Well the actual cost depends on the application. Sure it might be costly for ints, but for floating point numbers, I'm not so sure. Is you application performance sensitive? If its a normal application, and this function doesn't get called thousands or millions of times, then why not go with the straight forward solution

Answer (score 0):

When you convert a binary representation of a floating-point value into a decimal representation (typically by converting to text in order to display it), you'll typically end up with an unbounded series of decimal digits. When you set the precision of an output stream you tell the runtime library to limit the number of digits that it displays and to round the tail. What you're asking for here is essentially the same thing, but with a different arrangement of the digits than an output stream presents. The simplest way to do this is to use an output stream to generate however many digits you want, and then rearrange them as you would like:

```
std::string result;
std::ostring_stream out;
out << std::fixed << std::precision(12) << result;
// now fiddle with result however you'd like
```